# Smooth covers and local sections

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, covering-spaces

Let $\pi : \bar{M} \rightarrow N$ a smooth cover. Show that for each $q\in\bar{M}$ exists a local smooth section $\sigma : U \rightarrow \bar{M}$ of $\pi$ such that $q\in \sigma(U)$.

Here there is my own proof.

Let be $q$ a point of $\bar{M}$.

By definition of smooth cover, we can surely find an open set $U$ of $N$ such that $\pi$, restricted to every connected component $\tilde{U}$ of $\pi^{-1}(U)$,  is a diffeomorphism between $\bar{U}$ and $U$, where $\bar{U}$ is a neighborhood of $q$.

By setting  $$\sigma\equiv\pi^{-1}_{\big{|}{U}}$$ we have that $\pi\circ\sigma ={id}_{U}$ and $\sigma$ is continuos by definition.

Hence $\sigma : U\rightarrow\bar{M}$ is a local section of $\pi$.

Moreover, we have that $\sigma(U)$ is a neighborhood of $q$ and hence  $q\in \sigma(U)\subset{\bar{U}}$ (this last fact follows from continuity of $\sigma$).

Let me know if it is correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, but there are some minor issues:

1. You must start with an open $U$ such that $\pi(q) \in U$. This assures that $q \in \pi^{-1}(U)$, thus $q \in \bar U$ for some open $\bar U \subset \pi^{-1}(U)$ which is mapped by $\pi$ diffeomorphically onto $U$.
2. The connected components need not be mapped by $\pi$ diffeomorphically onto $U$. This is only true if $U$ is connected. If you want, you can w.l.o.g. assume this because in a manifold each point has arbitrarily small connected open neigborhoods.
   But there is no need to take a connected $U$, any evenly covered $U$ will do.
3. *By definition* you have $\sigma(U) = \bar U$.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!